# put LIMIT <chunk_size> in google cloud spanner delete query

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, scalability, google-cloud-spanner

my goal is to delete recrods in batch where I have a conditional query:

while(`select * from <table_name> where <condition_1> limit 1;`) exists,

```
delete from <table_name> where <condition_1> limit <chunk_size>;
```

using chunk_size to avoid deleting numerous rows in a single call.

Since spanner deletes using `Mutation.delete(tableName, keySet)` instead of a DML query like `delete from <table_name> where . . . limit <chunk_size>`. I'm wondering if there's a spanner way to put the `limit <chunk_size>` or alternate way to achieve the goal I mentioned above.

(I'm using scala, thus spanner java client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete rows based on a non key criteria you currently need to do this in two steps.

First run a query: `Select <PK columns> FROM <table_name> WHERE <condition_1> LIMIT <return_qualifying_rows_count>;`

Then in the second step you use the returned primary key(s) in the `Mutation.delete(tableName, keySet)` function

If you want to delete in batch, set the `<return_qualifying_rows_count>` to the number of rows you want to delete in batch. There is no limit on how many rows you can delete in one call.

Comment: sounds like a good solution! Though I'm wondering if given a large number of `return_qualifying_rows_count`, would it be efficient to fetch the PKs, transform it to a KeySet and finally deleting it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is currently the most efficient way to delete rows by non-key criteria. Currently, the only way to delete rows is via our APIs which expect a keyset as a selector. If you want to delete all rows however, you can do something like: 
`List<Mutation> mutations = new ArrayList<>();
mutations.add(Mutation.delete("tableName", KeySet.all()));
dbClient.write(mutations);`

Answer (score 1):

I found out it is ok to combine `select ... limit ...` and `delete from`, like this

`delete from TABLE where PK in (select PK from TABLE where CONDITION=VALUE limit COUNT)`

For example:

```
delete from actor where id in (select id from actor where gender = "man" limit 99)
```

Remember `COUNT` should be no greater than 10000 in this method since spanner quota for this is 20000, ref here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/quotas#limits_for_creating_reading_updating_and_deleting_data